# MongoDB pagination without skip and ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb, pagination

I want to implement a pagination mechanism in my project. I've read that using the naive skip & limit method can be slow as Mongo will read through anyway, so it's better to use an ordered column (like `_id`), limit the results, send the last `_id` to the client and then continue from there. However, my records are not using `ObjectId`, just a randomly generated `GUID`. The `_id` field is **still** indexed, so I assume it's in **some** order?

How can I use that in my advantage to implement a pagination mechanism? Do I have to sort my `_id` field before going through it everytime?

Comment: It doesn't matter which field and value you are using, as long as it has a unique non-sparse index on the field and you sort by this field. _id is used in the examples because it meets these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I used the _id field but just had to sort it so it’s in order then I could use the ‘$gt’ condition.